# Git - Reverted commits included in another merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have the situation that a few weeks ago, in my repository, the develop branch was more or less accidentally merged into the master. Do not ask me how or why, but it happened. The simplest solution at the time was just to revert the merge commit and move on with our stuff, as the master branch was again on our deployed state.

However, now the time has come to actually create the release that we intended a few weeks ago. To the stuff on develop at the time comes now a bunch of other stuff, about 20 commits were created before the incident, and about 20 commits after. My fear is, that if I try to merge the develop into the master again, the commits that were reverted before will not be applied again, since they already appear in the history. I am not absolutely sure of that, but I have encountered similar problems in the past, in which I just readded the changes manually and was done with it.

I have attached pictures of the network graph below, so you can understand what the situation is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is: If I now merge the develop branch into the master, with a pull request or otherwise, how can I make sure that the changes I made before the incident are applied? Do I have to revert the "Revert merge into master" commit before attempting this?

Comment: "Do I have to revert the "Revert merge into master" commit before attempting this?" you should rebase onto master so the develop branch so it includes the revert and then yes, revert the revert.

Comment: So I should basicall merge the current master into my develop, then revert ONLY the "Revert merge into master" commit, nothing else?

Comment: should do it.  You can always test it out on a branch off `develop` and `master`

Comment: That worked. If you want to convert the comments into a small answer I can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rebase onto master so the develop branch so it includes the revert and then yes, revert the revert the "Revert merge into master" commit